# AIC for semi-parametric model

Tags: nonparametric, aic

I have learnt the definition of AIC for parametric model. But, what I want to know is that is there a semi-parametric version of AIC?
Have you heard about it? And if you know, please show me a link, so I can have a look.

Comment: Not sure if this applies in your context, but perhaps of some interest: [1](http://archive.nyu.edu/bitstream/2451/14775/1/SOR-97-12.pdf) [2](http://www3.stat.sinica.edu.tw/statistica/oldpdf/A19n223.pdf)